# Visual Studio 2012 Project Properties Editor is Disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have problem with my visual studio. Something went wrong with my project properties and I always see everything disabled. It hapens even if I create new console application. 
 
Any ideas? I restarted all visual studio settings, restarted computer, uninstalled extensions, searched the web but nothing helped. 
[image: Disabled project properties]

Comment: what version is it? Express? Ultimate ?....

Comment: By any chance, have you checked whether project file is readonly or read-write?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2012 Proffesional Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2. Project file is writable. I even tried to run VS in admin mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Repair in add or remove programs and it is working fine now. Wonder what went wrong. I dont like this "it worked yesterday" problems.

Answer (score 0):

The same symptom occurs while running your program in Visual Studio using the debugger.

If the project properties are greyed out, first check if you are debugging. If you are, finish debugging, then look again at the property pages.